# How to access a winform textbox from Parallel.ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am processing a list of textfiles in C#. Because of the performance, I use the Parallel.ForEach for this. I need to write to the `richTextBox1` on my form, which file is being processed.

Since I was not able to access the form from different threads from the Parallel.ForEach, I created the `WriteToBox` method using Invoke.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private static Form2 frmReference;
    private delegate void SafeCallDelegate(string text)
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmReference = this;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> FindStrings(List<string> rccFiles)
    {
        Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> sensitiveData = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

        Parallel.ForEach(rccFiles, rccFile =>
        {
            //write which file is beeing processed
            WriteToBox("Searching in: " + rccFile);

           //some code
        });

        return sensitiveData;
    }

    public void WriteToBox(string text)
    {
        if (frmReference.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new SafeCallDelegate(WriteToBox);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            frmReference.richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + text);
            frmReference.richTextBox1.Update();
            frmReference.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, it will only write the first processed file and the form freezes (deadlock?). Do you have an idea how to write to a textbox from a parallel loop? Thanks for any advice! Regards, Martin

Answer (score 3):

Parallel.ForEach (running on UI thread) is waiting to all tasks to finish and so is the WriteToBox, because it wants to `Invoke`. These threads then get into deadlock. Easiest way to fix it is to replace `Invoke` to `BeginInvoke`.


Anothey way is to wrap Parallel.ForEach code into separate thread (non UI), since there is no need to this code to run on UI.

```
Task.Run(Parallel.ForEach(rccFiles, rccFile =>
{
    //write which file is beeing processed
    WriteToBox("Searching in: " + rccFile);

    //some code
}));
```